# Make action in another app trigger an action in my own

Tags: java, android, firebase, calendar, google-calendar-api

I've looked into using Google's Calendar API and provider and have found it is possible to read the user's calendar. This can be used to keep my app's inner calendar in sync with the Google calendar IF the user opens the app after making a change to their Google Calendar.

I am wondering if it is possible for my app to be notified whenever a change occurs in the Google Calendar so that my app may copy those changes and keep it in sync within my app's own online database.

This is because my app's functionality requires users to compare calendars but it is useless if a change occurs in the Google Calendar and then cannot be seen until the user opens my app again.

All ideas are appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer mate!\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to be notified whenever a change occur in your Calendar. [Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) allow you to find out about changes to events in your calendar.

The Google Calendar API provides push notifications that let you watch for changes to resources. You can use this feature to improve the performance of your application. It allows you to eliminate the extra network and compute costs involved with polling resources to determine if they have changed. Whenever a watched resource changes, the Google Calendar API notifies your application.

To [request push notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#making-watch-requests), you need to set up a notification channel for each resource you want to watch. After your notification channels are set up, the Google Calendar API will inform your application when any watched resource changes.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://exampledomain.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
  }
}
```